# How to make tasklist.exe run on windows 2000

Tags: new-operator

Can someone please tell me how to make tasklist.exe file run on Windows 2000. I downloaded the file from net & placed under the system32 folder. However when I tried to execute the file it prompted me a message "ERROR:the target system must be running Windows XP or above"

So can someone please tell me how to run this on windows 2000? I badly need this, as I am doing a batch script to find out the foreground processes running in my windows 2000 machine.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I looked but couldn't find a version for Windows 2000. But I did find this article on using an [alternative program](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_tasklistexe_and_why_dont_i_have_it.html).

Comment: how to write windows batch script to run procexp.exe?

Answer (score 0):

The original tasklist.exe will not work in stock Windows 2000 because it's looking for APIs which don't exist there. You can use a modified version created blackwingcat:

http://blog.livedoor.jp/blackwingcat/archives/1372175.html

Just download and unpack taskcmds.cab.